# Need recommendation for a table structure

Tags: sql-server, database-design

I have an entity which has 4 different types of property that could have only one value for each case which are boolean, decimal, string or text. I don't want to define the table with 4 boolean, decimal, nvarchar and ntext columns. What would you recommend to cover this case?

**Update:**

I'm using MS SQL Server.

Here is the class definition:

```
public class Foo
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Description { get; set; }
    public bool BooleanValue { get; set; }
    public decimal DecimalValue { get; set; }
    public string NVarcharValue { get; set; }
    public string NTextValue { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: Do you have a class definition or something that you can share to help illustrate your problem?

Comment: some databases support a `sql_variant` datatype, but expect difficulty if you ever want to change DBM.

Answer (score 1):

I'll presume that you want to use MS SQL Server.

If this is the case then I wouldn't use `ntext`  This datatype is due to removed in future versions of SQL Server.  If you really need to use a non-Unicode datatype then use `nvarchar`.  Another restriction of using `ntext` is that you can't convert it to a lot of the other datatypes. Of the 30 odd datatypes, you can only convert `ntext` to six of them.

What you could do in this scenario is have the following table structure.

```
Create Table dbo.PropertyInformation
(
PropertyId int identity(1,1) not null,
PropertyName varchar(50) not null,
PropertyTypeId int not null,
PropertyValue nvarchar(max)
)
```

Then add a lookup table to store your property types

```
Create table dbo.PropertyTypes
(
PropertyTypeId int identity(1,1) not null,
PropertyType varchar(50) not null
)
```

You can store any type of value in the PropertyValue column as `nvarchar` converts to almost all other datatypes - apart from image.  Read the PropertyType from the lookup table and convert the value of PropertyValue on the fly within your App.

Although, do you have a reason why you don't want to have 4 different columnns to store the property values?

[ntext datatype information](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187993.aspx)

[Casting & Converting in SQL Server](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187928.aspx) (The matrix of allowed conversions is about half way down the page)

Answer (score 0):

You could define 4 tables for each of the properties and each row of each table would have a foreign key to the entity that it belongs to.